# Euler 10th solution in Java

Tags: java

I've tried to solve this problem and write code but it doesn't work.  I tried with breakpoint it seems working but it doesn't.. where have I gone wrong?

10th euler problem:
The sum of the primes below 10 is 2 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 17.
Find the sum of all the primes below two million.

my java code:

```java
 public class Problem_010 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    long sum = 0;
    boolean control = false;

        for (int i = 3; i < 2000000; i+=2) {
            control = true;
            for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {

                if ((i % j) == 0) {
                    control = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (control == true) {
                sum = sum + i;                  
            }
        }

    System.out.println("Sum: " + (sum+2));
}

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work right"?

Comment: you get any error or wrong output? make things clear in question

Comment: You'll quickly find out that people wont take kindly to ambiguous "this just doesn't work, figure it out for me!" questions.

Comment: int sum = 2. You missed 2. Also, as an improvement, you don't need to check all the numbers to i. Checkout up to sqrt(i) is enough.

Comment: i didn't get any error or output and only i want to learn this, why? i optimized my code and it works now faster..

Answer (score 5):

The answer is right if you run it long enough, it is just very inefficient.  Try this instead.

```
public static void main(String... ignored) {
    long sum = 2;
    for (int i = 3; i < 2000000; i += 2) {
        if (isPrime(i))
            sum += i;
    }

    System.out.println("Sum: " + sum );
}

private static boolean isPrime(int i) {
    for (int j = 3; j * j <= i; j += 2) {
        if (i % j == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code will work, it'll just take a long time. There are much better approaches you can take in order to find the primes; take a look at the [sieve of Atkin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin)<sup>1</sup>, an algorithm commonly used to find primes less than a certain integer.

---

<sup>1</sup> The sieve of Atkin is an optimized version of the [sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). The latter should also be fast enough and will likely be easier to code, as @DennisMeng points out.

Comment: wouldn't the 'Sieve of Eratosthenes' be quicker?

Comment: @radimpe Sieve of Atkin is an optimized version of that.

Comment: Sieve of Eratosthenes is easier to code though, and it's plenty fast enough.

Comment: Since this problem is about to get prime numbers, I would stick to Sieve of Eratosthenes.

Comment: @DennisMeng You are right, I added that in.